# How to use Resources in Visual WebPart using VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I am implementing visual webpart in visual studio 2013 and when I am using resources in controls it throws errors

"/>

It was working well for VS 2010 but the problem in VS2013